# How to store/access multiple values of the same key in a map C++

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

So lets say I declare an unordered_map like this:

```
unordered_map<string, vector<string>> my_map;
```

And I have a list of values I want to store in it like this:

```
vector<string> vec1 = {"banana", "apple"}; 
vector<string> vec2 = {"banana", "banana"};
vector<string> vec3 = {"banana", "watermelon"};
```

if I go through and initialize each vector to the map, using the string in its 0th index as the key, like so:

```
my_map[vec1[0]] = vec1;
my_map[vec2[0]] = vec2;
my_map[vec3[0]] = vec3;
```

Would the unordered_map store all three of the vectors despite them having the same access key? And if I wanted to access each vector, is there a way I could do so in the same order that they appear in the list above?

So for example, if I did this:

```
 vector<string> output1;
 vector<string> output2;
 vector<string> output3;

 output1 = my_map["banana"];
 output2 = my_map["banana"];
 output3 = my_map["banana"];
```

which vectors would be assigned to output1, output2 and output3? I'm pretty sure it would be the same vector for all but how does unordered_map decide which one? And how can I make it so vec1 would be assigned to output1, vec2 to output2, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` stores only one value for each key - the last you assigned to it, in your case it's `vec3`. If you want to store several values for each key you can use [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) or [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap).

Comment: @Anton_Savin Thanks for the reply. I need to avoid multimaps for the time being and am instead looking for a way to circumvent this problem on a normal unordered_map. Would it be plausible to keep an int counter variable that I incremented for each addition to the unordered_map, and then added the counter to its key string like so: string fruit; fruit += fruit + counter; my_map[fruit] = vec2;  ?

Comment: @user5482356: If the apparently silly "need to avoid" requirement is your teacher's, then one good way to proceed is to implement yourself the extra functionality of a multimap. It's not difficult to do.

Answer (score 1):

If 2 elements have the same key then the first key value will be printed , others are ignored.

So Try the Map of Map:

**Sample Snippet :**

```
  std::multimap <int, xxx> stdBindListOuter;
  std::multimap <int, std::string>::iterator pos;
  std::multimap <int, xxx>::iterator posOuter;
```

xxx--> can be user-defined..

So more flexible to use this type of versions for your case. rather than Ordered or unordered map..